# Galaxy S I-9000 v2.2 contacts disappeared and home screen blank

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s

Yesterday, I picked up my phone and saw that the screen was black and unresponsive, also the lights on the two soft keys in the bottom were lit up. I tried tapping those keys and also the lock key but nothing changed so I took the battery out and restarted the phone. Then I saw that all my homescreens were blank except the first one which had google search widget(wasn't there before) and some other default widgets.Also the contacts stored on the phone were gone (google contacts and sim contacts are there).

In addition to those, my lock animation (the one that says "slide the glass") is gone. Now the phone opens up directly to home screen when I press the lock button. Also, the home button does open the screen light when the screen goes dark, but it won't get me to my home screen. One more problem, the menu which is displayed when you press and hold the lock button used to have 4 items (power off, data network open/close, silent mode open/close and flight mode open/close) but now it only has 1 item (power off). The last one, my phone seems to be giving the busy tone to anyone that calls me. I can call anyone with no problem but I can't receive calls. Text messages are fine too.

What can be the cause of this? Has anyone had any similar problem. btw I never messed with the roms or root or anything. I've been using it with the stock rom since I bought it.

The most important thing is the contacts that are stored in the phone. Can I recover those? If so how?

Thanks in advance.